# How to View data, based on date input(edittext)?

Tags: java, android, xml, date, crash

I wanted to do a view output using table layout.

My idea goes like this.
I have a main page, known as activity_main.xml
when you click on the cancel button, it will go to a summary page, 
know as data.xml.
In data.xml, I have a date edittext, whereby ,when I enter a date,eg 12/2/2013,
and after I click the button search, it will show me the record of it.
However, I'm not sure how to do it.
If I didn't enter any date and click "search", it will show all the records.

Right now,I am able to show all the records, without searching the data.
Below is my code.

Can someone kindly help me out with the search by date?
I hope that I've explained myself clear enough.

DBAdapter.java

```
public class DBAdapter {



    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE = "fuelprice";
    public static final String KEY_FUEL = "fuelpump";
    public static final String KEY_COST = "tcost";
    public static final String KEY_ODM = "odometer";
    public static final String KEY_CON = "fcon";

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "fuelLog";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;



    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table fuelLog (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "date text not null, fuelprice text not null, fuelpump text not null, tcost text not null, odometer text not null, fcon text not null);";


        private final Context context;    

        private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DBAdapter(Context ctx){
            this.context = ctx;
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
        {
            DatabaseHelper(Context context){
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
            {
                try{
                    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }//onCreate

            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
                onCreate(db);
            }//onUpgrade

        }//DatabaseHelper


        public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }//open


        //---closes the database---    
        public void close() 
        {
            DBHelper.close();
        }//close


        //---insert a log into the database---
        public long insertLog(String date, String fuelprice, String fuelpump,String tcost,String odometer,String fcon ) 
        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            initialValues.put(KEY_PRICE, fuelprice);
            initialValues.put(KEY_FUEL, fuelpump);
            initialValues.put(KEY_COST, tcost);
            initialValues.put(KEY_ODM, odometer);
            initialValues.put(KEY_CON, fcon);


            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }//insertLog






    // --retrieves all the data
       public Cursor getAllLog()
        {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_DATE, KEY_PRICE, KEY_FUEL,KEY_ODM,KEY_CON}, null, null, null, null, null);
        }


}
```

summary.java

```
  public class summary  extends Activity{
     TableLayout tablelayout_Log = null;
     Button searchButton = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data);



        tablelayout_Log = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_Log);

        tablelayout_Log.setStretchAllColumns(true);   
        tablelayout_Log.setShrinkAllColumns(true);   


        //View
                searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
                searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        try{
                            refreshTable();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.d("Fuel Log", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                }); 
                }//oncreate



            public void refreshTable()
            {
                tablelayout_Log.removeAllViews();
                TableRow rowTitle = new TableRow(this);
                rowTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                TextView title = new TextView(this);
                title.setText("Fuel Log");
                title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,18);
                title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);

                TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
                params.span = 5;

                rowTitle.addView(title, params);
                tablelayout_Log.addView(rowTitle);
                DBAdapter dbAdaptor = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try
                {
                    dbAdaptor.open();

                    cursor = dbAdaptor.getAllLog();
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    do{
                        long id = cursor.getLong(0);
                        String date = cursor.getString(1);
                        String price = cursor.getString(2);
                        String pump = cursor.getString(3);

                        String odometer = cursor.getString(4);
                        String fcon = cursor.getString(5);


                        TextView viewId = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        viewId.setText("" + id);

                        TextView viewDate = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        viewDate.setText(date);

                        TextView viewPrice = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        viewPrice.setText(price);

                        TextView viewPump = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        viewPump.setText(pump);


                        TextView viewOdometer = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        viewOdometer.setText(odometer);

                        TextView viewCon = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        viewCon.setText(fcon);

                        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                        row.addView(viewId);
                        row.addView(viewDate);
                        row.addView(viewPrice);
                        row.addView(viewPump);
                        row.addView(viewOdometer);
                        row.addView(viewCon);
                        tablelayout_Log.addView(row);
                    }
                    while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Fuel Log", e.getMessage());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cursor != null)
                        cursor.close();
                    if(dbAdaptor != null)
                        dbAdaptor.close();
                }
            }//refreshTable

        }//main
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TableLayout tablelayout_Contacts = null;
    Button insertButton = null;
    EditText nameEdit = null;
    EditText contactEdit = null;
    Button viewButton = null;
    Button deleteButton = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tablelayout_Contacts = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_Contacts);

            tablelayout_Contacts.setStretchAllColumns(true);   
            tablelayout_Contacts.setShrinkAllColumns(true);   

            nameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
            contactEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Number);







    insertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    insertButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            DBAdapter dbAdaptor = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            try{
                dbAdaptor.open();
                String name = nameEdit.getText().toString();
                String number = contactEdit.getText().toString();
                dbAdaptor.insertContact(name, number);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Contact Manager",e.getMessage());
            }
            finally{
                if(dbAdaptor != null)
                    dbAdaptor.close();
            }
        }
    });



    //View records
    viewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    viewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try{
                refreshTable();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Contact Manager",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    //delete records
    deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            DBAdapter dbAdaptor = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());

            try{
                refreshTable();
                String name = nameEdit.getText().toString();


                if(!name.equals(""))
                {
                    dbAdaptor.deleteContact(name);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Contact Manager",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });



    }//oncreate











    //refresh table


    public void refreshTable()
    {
        tablelayout_Contacts.removeAllViews();
        TableRow rowTitle = new TableRow(this);
        rowTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        TextView title = new TextView(this);
        title.setText("Contacts");
        title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,18);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);

        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();

        params.span =3;
        rowTitle.addView(title,params);
        tablelayout_Contacts.addView(rowTitle);
        DBAdapter dbAdaptor = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());

        Cursor cursor = null;

        try{
            dbAdaptor.open();
            cursor = dbAdaptor.getAllContacts();
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                long id = cursor.getLong(0);
                String name = cursor.getString(1);
                String contact = cursor.getString(2);

                TextView idView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                idView.setText("" + id);

                TextView nameView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                nameView.setText(name);

                TextView contactView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                nameView.setText(contact);

                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                row.addView(idView);
                row.addView(nameView);
                row.addView(contactView);

                tablelayout_Contacts.addView(row);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Contact Manager", e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
            if(dbAdaptor != null)
                dbAdaptor.close();


            }   
    }




}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


   <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/datetxtview"
                android:text="@string/date"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
              <EditText
                android:id="@+id/date" 
                android:text=""
                android:inputType="date" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
       </TableRow>

         <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/fuelpricetxtview" 
                android:text="@string/fuelprice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fuelprice" 
                android:text="" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
         <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/fuelpumptxtview" 
                android:text="@string/fuelpump"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fuelpump" 
                android:text="" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>


          <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/totalcosttxtview" 
                android:text="@string/totalcost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tcost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>



         <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/odometertxtview" 
                android:text="@string/odometer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/odometer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </TableRow>   
         <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/fctxtview" 
                android:text="@string/fc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>     
        </TableLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveBTN"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60px" >
        </Button>

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/updateBTN"
            android:text="Update"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60px" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBTN"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60px" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


 <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/datetxtview"
                android:text="@string/date"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/datepast" 
                android:text=""
                android:inputType="date" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

         <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/fctxtview" 
                android:text="@string/fc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fc" 
                android:text="" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
         <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/highpricetxtview" 
                android:text="@string/highprice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/highprice" 
                android:text="" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
         <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <Button
     android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Search" />
     <Button
     android:id="@+id/deleteBTN"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Delete" />
        <Button
     android:id="@+id/backBTN"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Back" />
        </TableRow>
       </TableLayout>

 <TableLayout    
         android:id="@+id/tableLayout_Log" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Follow these guidelines to improve your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a nullpointer that means that some object that is at line 205 in MainActivity or it is used at that line is null. Check that first and then try to run again.

Comment: searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
  searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  is the null But why?

Comment: Try something like this: View view = findViewById(R.id.tableRow4) and then searchButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);

Comment: I've change my code and edited my question,please take a look. your help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is here:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.d("Fuel Log", e.getMessage());
}
```

Not all throwables have a message and a `null` can be returned. A `null` cannot be logged. It causes the "println needs a message" exception in the stacktrace.

So first, change that to e.g.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Fuel Log", "", e);
}
```

This will log the exception with error level, empty message and with full stacktrace.

Then you can see what causes that exception in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Hello date type is not supported in Sqlite Database.you have assign date as text so it will take string so you need to keep string in proper order so that it can work as date search.

You can store date in form of 2013-12-23 (20131223) then you can get your query by passing date 
by the way you can try like below

```
 public ArrayList<String> getEventsForNotification(String dateSearch)

    {
     ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
        String sql="SELECT "+KEY_EVENT_NAME+" FROM "+ TABLE_EVENT +" WHERE SUBSTR("+KEY_EVENT_DATE+",6) like '"+dateSearch+"'";
        Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {

            do
            {
                arrayList.add(cursor.getString(0));
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
            cursor=null;
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

modify according to your need.